# Excited states using ORMAS flag in GAMESS

Tags: software, computational-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, gamess, excited-states

I am trying to calculate the excited states using single reference CISD on $\ce{CH3OH},$ using ORMAS' CI-X option in GAMESS. As a test example I am using the $\ce{CH3OH}$ that has 2 core, 7 occ. valence, 39 empty MOs (50 AOs, 48 MOs). I am unable to understand the `$ormas` flag in the following `ormas-meoh-cisd.inp` file:

```
!   single reference CISD on CH3OH, using ORMAS' CI-X option.
!          counting: 2 core, 7 occ. valence, 39 empty MOs (50 AOs, 48 MOs)
!          the resulting CI-SD has 53,964 Sz=0 A' determinants
!
 $contrl scftyp=rhf cityp=ormas runtyp=energy ispher=1 $end
 $system mwords=50 $end
 $basis  gbasis=ccd $end
 $guess  guess=huckel $end
 $scf    dirscf=.true. $end
 $trans  dirtrf=.true. $end
 $cidet  group=Cs stsym=Ap ncore=2 nact=46 nels=14 nstate=3 $end
 $ormas  nspace=2 mstart(1)=3,10 mine(1)=12,0
                                 maxe(1)=14,2 $end
 $data
Methanol...CISD...RHF/6-31G(d) geometry
Cs

H     1.0  -1.0616171503   0.8036449245   0.0000000000
O     8.0  -0.6870131482  -0.0653470836   0.0000000000
C     6.0   0.7093551399   0.0291827007   0.0000000000
H     1.0   1.0836641283   0.5408321444   0.8835398105
H     1.0   1.0975386849  -0.9797829903   0.0000000000
 $end
```

The following keywords are used in the `$ORMAS` section:

```
nspace=2
mstart(1)=3,10
mine(1)=12,0
maxe(1)=14,2
```

I can understand the `nspace = 2` means the active space is partitioned into doubly occupied + active and valence orbitals. However, I don't understand how the numbers pertinent to the rest of the flags in `$ORMAS` are chosen. Any explanation would be really helpful and appreciated.

Comment: It seems you may have accidentally made a [second account](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users/3556/debo-chaudhuri). You can use this [form](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to request that they be merged together.

Answer (score 3):

As specified in the [GAMESS Documentation](http://myweb.liu.edu/%7Enmatsuna/gamess/input/ORMAS.html):

- `nspace=n` means the active space will be split into $n$ groups.
- `mstart` sets the starting orbital for each of the $n$ groups. In your case, the first group extends from orbital 3 to orbital 9, while the second is from orbital 10 to `NCORE+NACT` (the number of core and active space orbitals). They mention that in this only makes sense if you have used `NORDER` in the guess section (I suppose otherwise there is no guarantee the active space is contiguous or that it is right after the core).
- `mine` sets the minimum number of electrons for each group.
- `maxe` sets the maxium number of electrons for each group.

Comment: +1 But a note for the future readers: the link posted here is not the official documentation and has not been updated since 2016. The latest documentation is here: https://www.msg.chem.iastate.edu/gamess/documentation.html (However, it's in txt format and not browsable as an html like the old link)